# Since what time or date updates have been available on the system?

Tags: updates

On Ubuntu 20.04 with

```
apt list --upgradable
```

I can see all available updates.

Is there also a way to see since what time or date these updates have been available on the system?

Comment: Are you asking "what time were the updates pushed into the repos" or "when did my system download the indexes and decide that an update is available"?

Comment: My question is: when did my system download the indexes and decide that an update is available?

Answer (score 1):

Not really, because it depends when you did an `apt update` which overwrites the database each time.

You could look at the [mailing list](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/focal-changes/2021-January/thread.html) which shows all updates to Focal. This shows when packages are promoted to the archive, in chronological order.

Comment: Hello popey,
thanks for your answer :)
could you please tell me how I can display how long the updates have been available on the system since the last get update? Maybe that would help me with my problem.

Comment: You haven't explained what the problem actually is. What is the actual goal here?

Comment: The problem is that I use a shell plugin for Icinga, I wrote myself, to check whether updates are available for the clients. The updates are carried out with unattended upgrades. Unattended upgrades carries out the updates a little delayed and as a result I have warnings in Icininga in the soft state that I do not want. Only when the update e.g. after a day it was not installed I want a warning in Icinga. As far as I know in Icinga I can not solve the problem. If would know since when an update is available I could enhance my script.